# mixed-effects logistic regression: different results with MASS and lme4

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I run a mixed-effects logistic regression with both MASS and lme4, but I get different results and I wonder whether (and where) there is something wrong.

my model is the following:

DV: synt_num (0 vs 1)

IVs:
voc1_tvl: continous

wo: dichotomous ("vs" and "vo")

verb: dichotomous ("c" and "t")

**USING MASS**

If I enter the following formula:

```
synt1 = glmmPQL (synt_num ~ voc1_tvl*verb*wo, random = ~1|participants, data=opz, family="binomial")
```

I get the following output

```
Linear mixed-effects model fit by maximum likelihood
 Data: ops 
  AIC BIC logLik
   NA  NA     NA

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | participants
        (Intercept)    Residual
StdDev:    21.50518 0.003233762

Variance function:
 Structure: fixed weights
 Formula: ~invwt 
Fixed effects: synt_num ~ voc1_tvl * verb * wo 
                                Value Std.Error DF    t-value p-value
(Intercept)                 -294.2627  22.41770 65 -13.126356  0.0000
voc1_tvl                       5.0748   0.27293 65  18.593945  0.0000
verb[T.t]                    152.6929  36.62349 47   4.169260  0.0001
wo[T.vs]                     327.9534  36.62150 47   8.955216  0.0000
voc1_tvl:verb[T.t]            -3.3897   0.45180 47  -7.502784  0.0000
voc1_tvl:wo[T.vs]             -5.3135   0.45178 47 -11.761381  0.0000
verb[T.t]:wo[T.vs]          -252.0190  73.23996 47  -3.441004  0.0012
voc1_tvl:verb[T.t]:wo[T.vs]    4.3519   0.90346 47   4.816905  0.0000
 Correlation: 
                            (Intr) vc1_tv vr[T.] w[T.v] vc1_tvl:v[T.]
voc1_tvl                    -0.992                                   
verb[T.t]                   -0.588  0.601                            
wo[T.vs]                    -0.588  0.601  1.000                     
voc1_tvl:verb[T.t]           0.588 -0.601 -1.000 -1.000              
voc1_tvl:wo[T.vs]            0.588 -0.601 -1.000 -1.000  1.000       
verb[T.t]:wo[T.vs]           0.588 -0.601 -1.000 -1.000  1.000       
voc1_tvl:verb[T.t]:wo[T.vs] -0.588  0.601  1.000  1.000 -1.000       
                            vc1_tvl:w[T.] v[T.]:
voc1_tvl                                        
verb[T.t]                                       
wo[T.vs]                                        
voc1_tvl:verb[T.t]                              
voc1_tvl:wo[T.vs]                               
verb[T.t]:wo[T.vs]           1.000              
voc1_tvl:verb[T.t]:wo[T.vs] -1.000        -1.000

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
          Min            Q1           Med            Q3           Max 
-3.8945233603 -0.0025293449 -0.0001866073  0.0018900747  3.2648586389 

Number of Observations: 120
Number of Groups: 67
```

Now, I have been told that if the SE is more than half the estimate the model is unreliable. However, this does not seem to be the case. That is, I see nothing wrong with the output. If I graph the data, these results kind of make sense (and it also goes according to predictions).

However, when I use lme4.....

**USING LME4**

If I use lme4 and the following code

```
>synt = glmer (synt_num ~ voc1_tvl*verb*wo + (1|participants), data=opz, family="binomial")
```

I get the following warnings

```
Warning in checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00757738 (tol = 0.001, component 1)
Warning in checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio
 - Rescale variables?
```

Now, why do I get warnings with lme4 and not with MASS??

As far as I understand the last warning could be solved by centering the only continuous variable I have (voc1_tvl). Am I wrong?

what about the other warnings?

If I force an out put out of this last model, I get something completely different from the previous MASS output

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: synt_num ~ voc1_tvl * verb * wo + (1 | participants)
   Data: opz

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   117.8    142.9    -49.9     99.8      111 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.8743 -0.3513  0.2158  0.3564  2.5211 

Random effects:
 Groups       Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 participants (Intercept) 1.074    1.036   
Number of obs: 120, groups:  participants, 67

Fixed effects:
                             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)                 -9.857319   4.856734  -2.030   0.0424 *
voc1_tvl                     0.153749   0.070039   2.195   0.0281 *
verb[T.t]                   -1.321681   6.377127  -0.207   0.8358  
wo[T.vs]                    11.089804   6.181132   1.794   0.0728 .
voc1_tvl:verb[T.t]          -0.004359   0.082863  -0.053   0.9580  
voc1_tvl:wo[T.vs]           -0.135696   0.081618  -1.663   0.0964 .
verb[T.t]:wo[T.vs]          -6.648285   8.266898  -0.804   0.4213  
voc1_tvl:verb[T.t]:wo[T.vs]  0.068410   0.105191   0.650   0.5155  
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
              (Intr) vc1_tv vr[T.] w[T.v] vc1_tvl:v[T.] vc1_tvl:w[T.] v[T.]:
voc1_tvl      -0.986                                                        
verb[T.t]     -0.528  0.493                                                 
wo[T.vs]      -0.834  0.829  0.431                                          
vc1_tvl:v[T.]  0.594 -0.579 -0.985 -0.490                                   
vc1_tvl:w[T.]  0.838 -0.848 -0.445 -0.986  0.518                            
vr[T.]:[T.]    0.583 -0.566 -0.794 -0.719  0.802         0.710              
v1_:[T.]:[T   -0.596  0.591  0.802  0.724 -0.828        -0.737        -0.986
convergence code: 0
Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00757738 (tol = 0.001, component 1)
Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio
 - Rescale variables?
```

Now, it might be that I've got too little data for the model and, in fact, if I enter the model without interactions I get no warnings and the following output

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: synt_num ~ voc1_tvl + verb + wo + (1 | participants)
   Data: opz

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   118.7    132.7    -54.4    108.7      115 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.2222 -0.4314  0.2455  0.4756  2.7784 

Random effects:
 Groups       Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 participants (Intercept) 0.4567   0.6758  
Number of obs: 120, groups:  participants, 67

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -3.96657    1.63767  -2.422 0.015432 *  
voc1_tvl     0.08047    0.02380   3.381 0.000721 ***
verb[T.t]   -2.13885    0.65960  -3.243 0.001184 ** 
wo[T.vs]    -0.18627    0.50623  -0.368 0.712901    
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
          (Intr) vc1_tv vr[T.]
voc1_tvl  -0.933              
verb[T.t]  0.271 -0.531       
wo[T.vs]  -0.168 -0.011  0.051
```

Hence, it might be, as Ben suggested below, that I should go after a more limited/reduced set of interactions.If enter the model using only two variables, but with one interaction as below:

```
> synt = glmer (synt_num ~ voc1_tvl*verb + (1|participants), data=opz, family="binomial")
```

again, I get the following warnings:

```
Warning in checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio
 - Rescale variables?
```

The output I get says that verb is not significant

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace
  Approximation) [glmerMod]
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: synt_num ~ voc1_tvl * verb + (1 | participants)
   Data: opz

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   118.5    132.5    -54.3    108.5      115 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.6510 -0.4008  0.2483  0.4341  3.0910 

Random effects:
 Groups       Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 participants (Intercept) 0.5154   0.7179  
Number of obs: 120, groups:  participants, 67

Fixed effects:
                   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)        -3.24172    2.16991  -1.494   0.1352  
voc1_tvl            0.06912    0.03060   2.259   0.0239 *
verb[T.t]          -3.80171    3.10388  -1.225   0.2206  
voc1_tvl:verb[T.t]  0.02172    0.03888   0.559   0.5764  
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) vc1_tv vr[T.]
voc1_tvl    -0.968              
verb[T.t]   -0.594  0.518       
vc1_tv:[T.]  0.653 -0.619 -0.977
convergence code: 0
Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio
 - Rescale variables
```

Why would it tell me that verb is significant when I enter only main effects, but not when I enter the interaction and only two predictors?

this is supsicious because if I use regression trees, verb is picked up and is significant.

It looks like when I use lme4, the model can't take interactions

**BIG QUESTIONS**

Can I trust the first (MASS) output?
 The kind answers below suggest that no, I can't

should I worry about what lme4 says?

in the second case, is my dataset beyond hope, giving that what I am investigating is very much the role of interactions?

Ben says:

**You might have an issue due to complete separation (i.e., the problem is your data, not the fitting procedures), but if you deal with that possibility and then try fitting the glmer model with other optimizers - and get similar results - then you can disregard the warnings.**

I tried to use the "nloptwrap”  (http://angrystatistician.blogspot.co.uk/2015/10/mixed-models-in-r-bigger-faster-stronger.html) using the following formulas

```
> synt.model = synt_num ~ voc1_tvl*verb*wo + (1|participants)
> fit <- glmer(synt.model, data=opz, verbose=TRUE, family=poisson(link=log), nAGQ=0, control=glmerControl(optimizer = "nloptwrap"))
```

However, I get the following warning

```
Warning in optwrap(optimizer, devfun, start, rho$lower, control = control,  :
  'verbose' not yet passed to optimizer 'nloptwrap'; consider fixing optwrap()
```

I therefore got rid of the verbose part and typed

```
> fit <- glmer(synt.model, data=opz, family=poisson(link=log), nAGQ=0, control=glmerControl(optimizer = "nloptwrap"))
```

and

```
> summary(fit)

 ( log )
Formula: synt_num ~ voc1_tvl * verb * wo + (1 | participants)
   Data: opz
Control: glmerControl(optimizer = "nloptwrap")

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   234.0    259.1   -108.0    216.0      111 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.96391 -0.45210  0.08698  0.26229  2.25782 

Random effects:
 Groups       Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 participants (Intercept) 0        0       
Number of obs: 120, groups:  participants, 67

Fixed effects:
                            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)                 -2.29833    1.57388  -1.460    0.144
voc1_tvl                     0.02457    0.01779   1.381    0.167
verb[T.t]                   -1.33202    2.46242  -0.541    0.589
wo[T.vs]                     2.05098    1.89449   1.083    0.279
voc1_tvl:verb[T.t]           0.01354    0.02807   0.482    0.630
voc1_tvl:wo[T.vs]           -0.02277    0.02207  -1.032    0.302
verb[T.t]:wo[T.vs]          -2.22007    3.31623  -0.670    0.503
voc1_tvl:verb[T.t]:wo[T.vs]  0.02114    0.03799   0.556    0.578

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
              (Intr) vc1_tv vr[T.] w[T.v] vc1_tvl:v[T.] vc1_tvl:w[T.] v[T.]:
voc1_tvl      -0.992                                                        
verb[T.t]     -0.639  0.634                                                 
wo[T.vs]      -0.831  0.824  0.531                                          
vc1_tvl:v[T.]  0.629 -0.634 -0.992 -0.522                                   
vc1_tvl:w[T.]  0.799 -0.806 -0.511 -0.988  0.511                            
vr[T.]:[T.]    0.475 -0.471 -0.743 -0.571  0.737         0.564              
v1_:[T.]:[T   -0.464  0.468  0.733  0.574 -0.739        -0.581        -0.991
```

The output is different from the one I had before and nothing is significant here (sic). Hence, I should worry about the first (lme4) output. Should I?

I am reading Bates’ observations

(https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/Theory.pdf).

I’ll try different optimisers and see whether results come up as different.

However, if results differ in terms of what reaches significance in the same way as the original model and the optimised with nloptwrap model **do** differ, does that mean that even the lme4 is not reliable?

thank you so much to anyone who has been brave (and kind) enough to read this post 'till the end

Comment: Have you tried just doing what the warning suggested, rescale the variables? Your predictors seem to be on very different scales.

Comment: Hi John, do you mean centering the continuous variable? Or does re-scaling imply something else/different? - thanks

Comment: Scaling... like turning a distance measured in millimetres to to metres. That's what its' asking you to do. It could be just multiplying a variable by 100 or dividing by it.

Answer (score 5):

## Why the whole analysis might be a little sketchy

One rule of thumb for statistical modeling (from Harrell's *Regression Modeling Strategies* book) is that you need an effective sample size of 10-20 observations per parameter you want to estimate. For binary data, "effective sample size" is min(number of 0 responses, number of 1 responses), so in the best case it will be half of your number of observations (less if most observations are 0 or most observations are 1), approx. 60 in your case.  You have 9 parameters (8 fixed-effect plus random-effects variance), so this is pushing it. Maybe there's a reduced set of interactions you are most interested in?

## Why I don't trust the MASS::glmmPQL results

- your data have a very small *effective sample size per cluster*: that is, these are binary data, with fewer than two observations per subject on average (120 total obs, 67 subjects). This is precisely the case where the way that one approximates the nasty integrals in the likelihood matters the most: in general, PQL is worst, followed by Laplace approximation (i.e. `glmer` default, with `nAGQ=1`), followed by Gauss-Hermite quadrature with more quadrature points (`glmer` with `nAGQ>1`; I would try `nAGQ=10`).
- In general for GLM(M)s, where the responses are on a unitless (log or logit scale), large effect sizes (say abs(beta)>10) are generally suspicious, indicating complete separation in the data set (e.g. see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38493/how-to-deal-with-quasi-complete-separation-in-a-logistic-glmm)) or some other problem.
- The correlations among the fixed effects show lots of perfect negative (-1.0) and positive (+1.0) values ... suggests a problem with the model

### Why the lme4::glmer results aren't quite so bad

- *A priori* we would expect `glmer` (which defaults to Laplace approximation) to do a little bit better than PQL, as mentioned above
- the parameter estimates and correlations are a little less extreme
- The parameter estimates and correlations among the fixed effects aren't as bad
- `?lme4::convergence` has some information on warnings and troubleshooting. A gradient of 0.007 isn't that bad, in my experience, and might be a false positive. You might have an issue due to complete separation (i.e., the problem is your data, not the fitting procedures), but if you deal with that possibility and then try fitting the `glmer` model with other optimizers - and get similar results - then you can disregard the warnings.

**updates**

- I wouldn't use `nAGQ=0`, that's in the wrong direction (you should probably be using `nAGQ`>1 rather than the default of `nAGQ`=1)
- if you get different results **with different optimizers**, **with `nAGQ`>1**, then I would worry. You can try

```
source(system.file("utils", "allFit.R", package="lme4"))
allFit(original_fit)
```

to try out all the different available optimizers on the original fit. In general the fit with the lowest AIC/negative log-likelihood is the one you can believe the most ...)
- at that point I would probably say that yes, your model is too complex for the data, so you need to do something simpler
- but in any case I would recommend *looking at your data* to see if there are any surprising phenomena (e.g. extreme values/outliers at the level of individual data points, participants, or combinations of factors)

Comment: Hi Ben, thank you for your answer. I pressed the useful answer arrow. There are still a few doubts that I struggle with. I put my thought by editing my questions , as it'd be too long for a comment.